# Height MapFragment Layout not work

Tags: java, android, layout, fragment

I'm build an app that contain two tabhost (top and botton) and in one tab, I want to put a Google Map through the Google API. All works well but the map does not display correctly. You can see better in this picture:

[image]

My code is:

fragment_mapa.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MapaFragment.java

```
public class MapaFragment extends Fragment {
    public MapaFragment(){}

    public GoogleMap mapa;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mapa, container, false);

        if (container != null) {
            container.removeAllViews();
        }

        GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setBar();

        //Asigno el nombre de la vista e integro tabhost-sliding
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setTitle("Mapa");
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).integrationMenu();

        return rootView;

    }


    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        Log.d("DESTROY", "onDestroyView");

        Fragment f = getActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        if (f != null) {
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

And my activity_main.xml that contain the two tabhost and a framelayout that call the fragments:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Estructura de los dos tabhost -->
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- TABHOST SUPERIOR -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/l1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_above="@+id/l2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

            <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
                android:id="@+id/tabhost_sup"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TabWidget
                        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dip"
                        android:layout_weight="0"/>


                    <ScrollView 
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="#ffffff">
                        <FrameLayout
                            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="0"/>
                    </ScrollView>

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- TABHOST INFERIOR -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/l2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light" >

            <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
                android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0"/>

                    <TabWidget
                        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0" 
                        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"       
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"       
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: try removing scrollview !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION (by [Hardik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1135548/hardik)):

Remove the scrollview in my activity_main.xml and it works well.

Answer (score 3):

Removing scrollview is not convinient solution.Instead of it try `android:FillViewPort="True"` for `Scrollview` in your `layout` solve your problem for all screen where you may require scroll for your activity content.Hope this helps you!!

Comment: Nope doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Use hierarchiviewer of android tools to check layout values.

Answer (score 0):

For the future:
If you have a ScrollView then elements must specify their height (width for horizontal scroll view) otherwise what height should they have, infinite?

I also had an issue where the exact thing happened when placing the map fragment inside a Relative Layout that had height = Wrap_Content, with minimum height.
Setting a constant height resolved the issue, same idea.

Answer (score 0):

came across this same issue but my map fragment is inside a scrollview and it needs to have a scrollview since there are also other views aside from the map. if it only contains the map, then yes scrollview is not needed.